# When did Lucifer's fall take place?

Tags: satan

Was it the act of seducing Eve to eat the apple that was his downfall, was he already fallen before that, or was it after?

Comment: Is the question when did the devil rebel against God or when did he fall from heaven?

Answer (score 4):

That happened before the Garden of Eden incident.  Before then, he walked in heaven (on the holy mount of God).

[Ezekial 28:14-15 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel%2028:14-15&version=NIV)

> **14** You were anointed as a guardian cherub,     for so I ordained you. 
>   You were on the holy mount of God;     you walked among the fiery
>   stones.  **15** You were blameless in your ways     from the day you were
>   created     till wickedness was found in you.

He was actually cast down because he became proud.

[Ezekial 28:17 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel%2028:17&version=NIV)

> Your heart became proud     on account of your beauty,  and you
>   corrupted your wisdom     because of your splendor.  So I threw you to
>   the earth;     I made a spectacle of you before kings.

Then he thought that he could be God, that he could take God's place in the universe as ruler of it:

[Isaiah 14:13-14 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2014:13-14&version=NIV)

> **13** You said in your heart,     “I will ascend to the heavens;  I will
>   raise my throne     above the stars of God;  I will sit enthroned on
>   the mount of assembly,     on the utmost heights of Mount Zaphon. **14** I will ascend above the tops of the clouds; 
>     I will make myself like the Most High.”

That was his downfal:  Pride--he thought he was as good as God.

Comment: I down voted because, in reading said chapters, it is very apparent that these prophecies are about men - the cited Ezekiel 28 about the King of Tyrus, and Isaiah 14 - while attributed to Lucifer/Satan - is clearly in reference to a man. God did not tell these prophets to go tell Satan these prophecies - instead they were to be delivered to specific men for a purpose. Even simpler still - Satan is either a fallen angelic being (Cherub) or a man - as both prophecies seem to indicate (as the beginning of Ez. 28 is about the Prince of Tyrus).